# sql, select top 5 occurences for certain dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with diagnosecodes on my sql server. On several days some diagnoses are set and pushed in the table.

Table (diagnoses) looks like this: 
Diagnose, Diagnosecode, Date.

What im trying to output with sql is:
The top 5 most occurred diagnosecode's on certain days (from X days till now) like this:

```
10 sept 2015 : 
100 times 1157 (diagnosecode)
90 times 11337 (diagnosecode)
80 times 111237 (diagnosecode)
70 times 112312357 (diagnosecode)
60 times 1112317 (diagnosecode)

9 sept 2015 : 
100 times 1157 (diagnosecode)
90 times 11337 (diagnosecode)
80 times 111237 (diagnosecode)
70 times 112312357 (diagnosecode)
60 times 1112317 (diagnosecode)

8 sept 2015 : 
100 times 1157 (diagnosecode)
90 times 11337 (diagnosecode)
80 times 111237 (diagnosecode)
70 times 112312357 (diagnosecode)
60 times 1112317 (diagnosecode)
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT TOP(5) count([diagnosecode]) as occurences, diagnosecode,     
FROM diagnoses 
WHERE date = SYSDATETIME()
GROUP BY diagnosecode 
ORDER BY date DESC, COUNT([diagnosecode]) DESC
```

It only works for today. I dont know how to make the query work for multiple days. How would I approach this issue?

Comment: I I don't know `"I have a table with diagnosecodes on my sql server"` on **MySQL Server** or on **my MS SQL Server** ;)

Comment: Remove the where condtion

Comment: its MS SQL server!! sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want five on each day, then use window functions:

```
SELECT date, occurrences, diagnosecode,     
FROM (SELECT diagnosecode, date, COUNT(*) as occurrences,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
     FROM diagnoses 
     GROUP BY diagnoses, date
    ) dd
WHERE seqnum <= 5
ORDER BY date DESC, occurrences DESC;
```

Note: if the date really has a time component, then you will want to cast it to `date` to extract only the date portion.

Comment: beat me to it! Good post

Answer (score 0):

Remove the where clause

```
SELECT TOP(5) count([diagnosecode]) as occurences, diagnosecode,     
FROM diagnoses 
GROUP BY diagnosecode 
ORDER BY date DESC, COUNT([diagnosecode]) DESC
```